# How can I make the transform to keep moving the direction it was moving when pausing and then resuming?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.GlobalIllumination;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Moving : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform destination;
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    private Coroutine movementCoroutine;
    private bool pause = false;
    private Vector3 startPosition;

    private void Start()
    {
        startPosition = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            pause = false;
            MoveToDestination();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            pause = true;
        }
    }

    private void MoveToDestination()
    {

        // if the coroutine is still running, stop it
        if (movementCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(movementCoroutine);
        }

        // start the coroutine
        movementCoroutine = StartCoroutine(MoveToDestinationCoroutine());
    }

    // the coroutine
    private IEnumerator MoveToDestinationCoroutine()
    {

        // while this object is not at the destination
        while (transform.position != destination.position)
        {
            if (pause)
                break;
            // move it towards the destination, never moving farther than "moveSpeed" in one frame.
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destination.position, moveSpeed);

            // wait until next frame to continue
            yield return null;
        }

        while (transform.position != startPosition)
        {
            if (pause)
                break;
            // move it towards the destination, never moving farther than "moveSpeed" in one frame.
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, startPosition, moveSpeed);

            // wait until next frame to continue
            yield return null;
        }

        StartCoroutine(MoveToDestinationCoroutine());
    }
}
```

I'm using the bool flag pause variable to pause and resume.

Pressing space to start moving then pressing s to pause and then space to resume the movement from the current paused position.

The problem is when it's resuming the movement it's not moving to the direction it was moving. It will resume the movement always to the left side even if it was moving to the right.

space key to start and resume and s key for pause.

Update :

I changed the pausing part to this :

```
private IEnumerator MoveToDestinationCoroutine()
    {
        // while this object is not at the destination
        while (transform.position != destination.position)
        {
            if (pause)
            {
                yield return null;
            }
            else
            {
                // move it towards the destination, never moving farther than "moveSpeed" in one frame.
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destination.position, moveSpeed);

                yield return null;
            }
        }

        while (transform.position != startPosition)
        {
            if (pause)
            {
                yield return null;
            }
            else
            {
                // move it towards the destination, never moving farther than "moveSpeed" in one frame.
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, startPosition, moveSpeed);

                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why break when you pause? You could just "yield return null" if paused and move in an else block. It is not great for performance (no worse than the movement itself) but it means you don't have to make any major code changes.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson I changed the code for the pausing and it's working. Can you look at my question I edited it with the code after the changes and it's working for the pausing and resuming. The problem is still for the direction. If the transform is moving to the right and I make pause then resume it will resume moving to the left and not to the right the direction it was moving to.  What should I do to keep it moving the direction it was moving ?

Comment: Note that the else in the while loop is not necessary, if you say `if(!pause) { transform.position = ... }` and after the if you yield return null. If its paused it skips over that if and goes to yield.

Comment: Is your destination moving by any chance?

Comment: Also it looks like you are restarting your "MoveToDestination" function when pausing and unpausing. So if you already went to the destination and are returning, unpausing will make you go back to the destination. Maybe just set pause to false when you press space, and start your coroutine in a different location (maybe OnEnable or OnStart since it looks like you are trying to make an infinite loop).

Comment: That looks like a solution worth posting as an Answer, @BenjaminDangerJohnson. 

Comment: Nope just instructions on how to work out the answer out for oneself. Seemed like a good learning opportunity.